# XML and PHP - If node exists, overwrite the data, if not, create a new one

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I'm building some sort of signature builder using a mix of HTML5 canvas, PHP and XML. What I need is that when the "first name" typed in that input already exists in the XML file, it detects if it already exists in the XML file, and with a confirm javascript window ask me if I want to replace that section, or cancel. And if the "first name" entered is new, and it's not in the xml file yet, it would automatically create a new section with the data entered.

Here's my HTML code (form part only)

```
<form name="signature">
First name:<input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname">
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('test2.xml');

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];

$xml->signature = "";
$xml->signature->fname = $fname;
$xml->signature->lname = $lname;

if(isset($xml->signature->fname = $fname)) { 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>return confirm('This first name already exists, overwrite it?');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($fname + ' saved as a new signature');</script>";
}

$doc->save('test2.xml');

?>
```

And my XML structure code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<signatures>

  <signature>
    <fname>John</fname>
    <lname>Doe</lname>
  </signature>

    <signature>
    <fname>Bob</fname>
    <lname>Funny</lname>
  </signature>

</signatures>
```

If I enter the "John Testing" in the form for example, it needs to detect that there's already a "John" in the XML file, so it would ask me if I want to replace the currently saved John Doe by John Testing. If I enter "Denis Tester" for example, well since there's no Denis, the XML file would become :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<signatures>

  <signature>
    <fname>John</fname>
    <lname>Doe</lname>
  </signature>

    <signature>
    <fname>Bob</fname>
    <lname>Funny</lname>
  </signature>

  <signature>
    <fname>Denis</fname>
    <lname>Tester</lname>
  </signature>

</signatures>
```

I've made some research and I'm pretty I need to use the isset function to scan the XML file. But I can't make it work.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fname = "John";
$lname = "Testing";

// find with xpath point to signature which fname is equal what we want
$signs = $xml->xpath('//signature[fname = "'.$fname.'"]');

// if (count($signs) > 1)  // What to do if some Johns found ?

if (count($signs) == 1) $signs[0]->lname = $lname;           // Found one element
else {                                                       // Not found - add
   $sign = $xml->addChild('signature');                      // Add signature child to root element
   $sign->addChild('fname', $fname);                         // Add names as cildren of signature
   $sign->addChild('lname', $lname); 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't make it work. Can you provide some explanation too? Just so I understand better what was the things that was not working in my code. Thanks a lot again

Comment: look there - https://eval.in/379732 Maybe, it helps. Else, ask what you don't understand

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can I still use :
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];

It does not seem to work when I do that. Please see my full code in that fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6rw9bmx4/1/ (the PHP code is in the JS section, and the XML code is in the CSS section)...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Awesome! Everythings working now. Thanks a bunch splash58. The comments you added really helped me understand better what I did wrong at first.